# iOS objective-C: using modulo on a float to get "inches" from Feet

Tags: ios, objective-c, c, modulo

I am trying to make a simple objective-C height converter. The input is a (float) variable of feet, and I want to convert to (int) feet and (float) inches:

```
float totalHeight = 5.122222;
float myFeet = (int) totalHeight; //returns 5 feet
float myInches = (totalHeight % 12)*12; //should return 0.1222ft, which becomes 1.46in
```

However, I keep getting an error from xcode, and I realized that the modulo operator only works with (int) and (long). Can someone please recommend an alternative method? Thanks!

Comment: Yes, modulo works for integers (non-decimals) only. Just like what you did, cast it to integer, then modulo .

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Even modulo works for float, use :

`fmod()`

You can use this way too...

```
float totalHeight = 5.122222;
float myFeet = (int) totalHeight; //returns 5 feet
float myInches = fmodf(totalHeight, myFeet);
NSLog(@"%f",myInches);
```

Comment: `float myInches = fmodf(totalHeight, myFeet);`   You have to multiply it by 12.

Comment: @shim: The OP does't want All feet to be converted to inches... He wanted only fraction of feet in inches, and Feet in whole number.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you use

```
CGFloat myInches = totalHeight - myFeet;
```

Comment: Yes, that is so obvious! I should use stack overflow past 3am. Thanks a lot.

Comment: you should not ask to accept the answer...if OP likes other like you will get +votes.. :)

Comment: @AnoopVaidya Yep, I know what you are referring to, but you know some newcomers are always forgetting to accept answer. I'm not sure about this and I saw OP's comment that it seems my answer answered OP's questions. So I just add a reminder. Is this clear?

Comment: Sunkehappy... your answer certainly helped in my case, but I think Anoop's operation really gets to the heart of the matter

Comment: @jake9115 I've also learned from Anoop's answer. I've not heard of that before.

Answer (score 0):

As answered earlier, subtracting is the way to go. Just remember to convert the one tenths of feet to inches by multiplying with 12:

```
float totalHeight = 5.122222;
int myFeet = (int) totalHeight;
float myInches = (totalHeight - myFeet) * 12;
```